# Aptana search open files does not work

Tags: aptana

I am trying to use the search function of Aptana to search in all open files.
I have set the scope to *open files* and I know for certain the criteria exist.

Can anyone tell me what it can be?

Comment: Perhaps you have selected one of the options that are limiting your search? Is case-sensitivity, whole word, search selection, or regular expression set? Is your project set to "Build Automatically", or has it been built recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. Aptana needs to have a project file to search in all other files

Comment: Yes, you have to right click on the folder and click: Promote to Project... Then you have to search in the aptana created project, not in the local files like you tried before.